# Calling GORM from background thread

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am launching a background thread from a Spring Bean in Grails 2.4.3. In this thread I am calling: `User.findAll()`

I was expecting an exception as there shouldn't be a Hibernate session associated to this created thread. But it works.

Why is it working?

**Edited:**

Actually if I create a new thread in `BootStrap.groovy`, it also works:

```
def init = {
  new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        def users = User.findAll()
        println users.size()
    }
  }).start()
}
```

In this case `User` is the Spring Security domain class, but it also works with any other domain class.

Comment: It's going to be impossible to answer this question without knowing all the details on how the Bean is being created, how it's calling `User.findAll()`, and so forth. Post your configuration and source for the related portions.

Comment: I've edited my question adding more details.